# ios push notification web server on 2mhost.com

Tags: php, ios, webserver

I am trying to use push notification on my app, I followed the tutorial.When I try the command `php pushMe.php` (this is my php file to send notification) on terminator, it works. My iphone got the message.But when I move my file to web server (2mhost.com) it does not work.
Can somebody tell me Why.
By the way,the socket and openssl are enabled on the server.

Comment: post logs from the server, configuration details (php version for example) and information about paths to APNS certificates.

Comment: paths of APNS is correct,because they are in same folder.    the php file always print                                                                    stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Connection timed out) in /home/lidaoxin/public_html/TIMServer/test/pushMe.php on line 21
Failed to connect: 110 Connection timed out

Comment: At first glance looks like firewall problem. This is quite common issue with APNS. Check if connections on port `2195` are not blocked by the server/isp/anything.